# É correto omitir o valor "true" dos atributos boolean inseridos nos elementos da HTML?

Tags: html, html5

Quando inserimos atributos *boolean* nos elementos (*tag*) `<html>` não precisamos informar o valor `true`, sendo que sua simples presença já confirma, por padrão, que este atributo esteja ativo. Exemplo:

```
<html lang="pt-BR" spellcheck>
   <body>
      <p contenteditable="true">Texto será verificado se conter erros!</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Repare que o atributo `spellcheck` no elemento `html` está sem o valor `"true"` porém, a gramática será verificada em qualquer elemento filho da raiz `html`.

Pergunta: é correto o usar atributos *boolean* sem informar seu valor? Qual a vantagem ou desvantagem? Alguma convenção de uso? Obrigada!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade o correto [segundo a especificação](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#boolean-attributes) é que não tenha a *string* indicando `true` ou `false`. Os principais navegadores interpretam estes valores booleanos, mas está fora do padrão, seria uma extensão. Então é correto omitir, ainda que colocá-lo possa funcionar na maioria das situações. Citação da especificação:

> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.